# Missing method driver drom for apt on kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu, 22.04

I have a relatively fresh install of kubuntu 22.04 lts. I have made very few changes to apt other than add a few repositories for third party applications. However recently while running a system update using:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

I receive the following warning that halts any upgrades from happening

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/drom could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-drom installed?
E: Failed to fetch drom://Kubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I cannot find any mention of the package **apt-transport-drom** on the web or by trying an apt search for it. All results refer to a different package **apt-transport-https** instead.
Any help on trying to fix this issue or understand why it is happening would be fantastic!!!

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your sources list. I believe it should be *cdrom*.

Comment: From your question I have made very few changes to apt other than add a few repositories for third party applications. Adding any PPA is making a MAJOR change to your system. You are adding untested and unverified software to the OS. The first thing to remove would be the PPA.